# Duda con ejercicio de entidad relación, Bases de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Tengo una duda en un ejercicio de entidad relación y quería pediros ayuda para ver si voy en lo cierto.

Se trata de realizar el diseño de la base de datos (en el modelo E/R) para una cadena de hoteles.

Cada hotel (del que interesa almacenar su nombre, dirección, teléfono, año de construcción, etc.) se encuentra clasificado obligatoriamente en una categoría (por ejemplo, 3 estrellas), pudiendo bajar o aumentar de categoría. Cada categoría tiene asociadas diversas informaciones, como, por ejemplo, el tipo de IVA que le corresponde.

Los hoteles tienen diferentes clases de habitaciones (suites, dobles, individuales, etc.). Las habitaciones se numeran de forma que se pueda identificar fácilmente la planta en la que se encuentran.

Las reservas las pueden realizar tanto personas particulares como agencias de viajes. En la reserva figurarán el nombre, dirección, teléfono y otros datos relativos a la persona que realiza la reserva. En caso de tratarse de una agencia de viajes se necesitan los mismos datos, además del nombre de la persona para quien la agencia de viajes está realizando la reserva. También se deberá indicar la categoría del hotel (o el hotel) que se desea, el período de la estancia y la clase de habitación.

El sistema debe gestionar los clientes de la cadena de hoteles, lo que supone almacenar los datos de las personas que han sido huéspedes de algún hotel de la cadena, sus diferentes estancias, gastos realizados y las facturas asociadas.

La tarifa de las habitaciones depende además del hotel y de la clase de habitación, así como de la temporada (alta, baja, etc.) de que se trate.

Mi duda es si la entidad reserva podría ser una jerárquica completa exclusiva, de la que salgan cliente particular y agencia de viajes ¿o cómo lo podría enfocar?

Answer (score 2):

La entidad Reserva debe estar entre el Hotel y el Cliente. Habitualmente una reserva de habitación no se corresponde con una reserva de habitación concreta, es una entidad derivada.

Hoteles 1 - n Reservas 1 - n Clientes 1 - n Agencias

Por otro lado tenemos la asignación de reservas a las habitaciones

Hoteles 1 - n ReservaHabitaciones 1 - n Reservas

Al principio tienes Reservas de n clientes de n Agencias, pero no se han asignado a ninguna habitación en concreto, aunque sabemos a que hotel va dirigida la reserva.

A medida que el hotel gestiona sus reservas les va asignando habitación, y ahí ya tiene relacionada toda la información del cliente.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo.

Perdona que te siga molestando, pero ¿sería mucho pedir un ejemplo visual? He leído tres veces y he intentado plasmarlo en folio, pero no consigo entender lo que me has explicado.

Por otro lado, me salta una duda y es que en el ejercicio se expone que una reserva puede ser hecha a un hotel o a una categoría, ¿podría ser eso una relación exclusiva?

De nuevo, muchas gracias por tu tiempo!